# jquery (server side) search and sorting using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, sorting

I tried to create search and sort from live URL using Ajax , i used do search function and i managed to retrieve the data from the URL .

I am showing Ajax response in select options as below code. I want to sort the select options in order of values (level values),the values are retrieved randomly in the results.

How can I combine search and sort function for that ?I used lots of tutorials to do that. To anyone who knows please help me to do that. Thank you.

Please provide a solution to automate sort data with the current search function on values basis (by level) . Sample of the current results  like :

So far I have this code:

```js
function doSearch() {
    $.Ajax({
          URL: 'https://live.ksmobile.net/live/BOYS',
          data: {
            page_size: 10,
            page_index: current_page
          },
          cache: false,
          type: 'GET',
          datatype: 'JSON',
          success: function(r) {
              var max = $('#limit').VAL();

              if (r.data.video_info.length < max) max = r.data.video_info.length;

              for (index = 0; index < max; index++) {
                var entry = r.data.video_info[index];
                var level = parse Int(entry.level);

                if ((level > $('#min').val()) && (level < $('#max').val())) {
                  count++;
                  var HTML = '<div class="entry ' + '"><h="' + entry + '">';
                  HTML += '<h3>Level: <span>' + entry.level + '</span> <span>' + entry.name + '' + '</span>id:<span>' + entry.heat;
                  HTML += '</div>';
                  $('#main').append(HTML);
                }
              }
```

Comment: Are those typos in your code or only in the question here: `parse Int`, `$('#limit'). VAL();`, `$('#min'). val()`, `$('#max'). val()` and `$('#main'). append(HTML)` ? -- Fix that first and retry.

Comment: Please provide the HTML and the entire Javascript code, because some variables are missing and also there are some spaces as Louys mentioned above.

Comment: How can i share the  HTML with JS code ? Is there away to attach file here?

Comment: jQuery is not server side

Comment: Working in client side.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom sort function which would look something like:

```
function sortResults(array) {
    array.sort(function(x, y) {
        if (parseInt(x.level, 10) < parseInt(y.level, 10)) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (parseInt(x.level, 10) > parseInt(y.level, 10)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
}
```

and then call it before your for loop:

```
sortResults(r.data.video_info);
```

You could also use a library like lodash to save some trouble and then use:

```
r.data.video_info = _.sortBy(r.data.video_info, item => {
    return _.parseInt(item.level);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i tried the custom sort array but it fails to sort either,how can i share my HTML with the entire JS code.

Comment: Don't see why it wouldn't work. I tested it with an example. can you provide the array you're iterating over? i.e `r.data.video_info`

Comment: It works partially ,the array in live URL "https://live.ksmobile.net/live/BOYS" ,the search function retrieve data and display them in html pages so the sort function only work page by page while i would like to sort the array in all pages at once.

Comment: Actually the custom sort is working alphabetically like( 2,22,3,30,36,4,45,...) so the sorting is invalid.

Comment: updated the solution to sort by numbers rather than strings

Comment: @ Urirot The updated solution is not working but i modified your first sort function and it works : function arr(a,b) {
  return parseInt(b.level, 10) - parseInt(a.level, 10); but the solution works for the current page ,appreciate your help if you can provide solution to sort the values in all page index using Ajax .